# reloadData when loop is done

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform

I have a loadItem functions which is suppose to load items from a parse server. This include a loop where i'm at the end is saving the data to an array:

```
itemArray?.addObject(arrayDic)
```

When this is saved i would like to reloadData of the collectionView. therefor i've inserted it into a dispatch_async block, but it still seems like it is being run before the data is saved into the itemArray array since the itemArray.count is 0 and i've checked inside the loop that the data is saved into the array. What am i doing wrong?

```
func loadItems() {
    var query = PFQuery(className:"Items")
    query.orderByAscending("createdAt")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            for object in objects {

                var imageRelation: PFRelation = object.relationForKey("pictures")


                var query = imageRelation.query()
                query.orderByDescending("createdAt")

                query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (imageObjects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {

                        var theArray = imageObjects as NSArray

                        var arrayDic = NSMutableDictionary()


                        let imageFile = theArray.objectAtIndex(0).objectForKey("image") as PFFile
                        imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                            (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                            if !(error != nil) {
                                let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                                arrayDic.setValue(object.objectForKey("price"), forKey: "price")
                                arrayDic.setValue(image, forKey: "image")
                                itemArray?.addObject(arrayDic)

                            }
                        }


                    }
                }



            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                println(itemArray?.count)
                self.collectionView.reloadData()

            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog("Error: %@ %@", error, error.userInfo!)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're doing two nested calls to "`query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`" and your `reloadData` call happens in the outside `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`.  What happens if you put the `reloadData` into the inner block?

Comment: then it will loop several times?

Comment: Since the outer `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` is already running in the background, why not refactor the inner block to run synchronously (or as part of the outer loop), via `findObjects`?  Then, when everything is done being found, you can call `reloadData` at the end of the outer (and only) block.

Comment: Could u give an example not sure i completely understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not advise trying to make the requests synchronous (as that can significantly slow down the process, unless you scheduled them to run concurrently on some concurrent background queue). I would suggest, instead, a pattern that allows you to keep the asynchronous requests, but notifies you of their completion. One such pattern is the dispatch group, in which you:

- create a dispatch group:

  ```
  let group = dispatch_group_create()
  ```
- for every iteration of your loop, call `dispatch_group_enter`:

  ```
  dispatch_group_enter(group)
  ```
- win the completion block of the asynchronous method, call `dispatch_group_leave`:

  ```
  dispatch_group_leave(group)
  ```
- specify what you want to do when the dispatch group is complete:

  ```
  dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
      println(self.itemArray?.count)
      self.collectionView.reloadData()
  }
  ```

  When all of the calls to `dispatch_group_enter` are offset by the final `dispatch_group_leave` call, the notification block will be called for you.

So, looking at the code as you loop through the objects, it might look something like:

```
let group = dispatch_group_create()

for object in objects {

    dispatch_group_enter(group)

    // do some stuff

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (imageObjects: [PFObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            // do some more stuff

            imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

                if !(error != nil) {
                    // do even some more stuff
                }

                dispatch_group_leave(group)
            }
        } else {
            dispatch_group_leave(group)
        }
    }
}

dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    println(self.itemArray?.count)
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Their are other functionally equivalent patterns (e.g. custom concurrent dispatch queue with the final `reloadData` dispatched with a barrier; make these individual requests `NSOperation` objects that you add to `NSOperationQueue` and create separate completion operation that is dependent upon those other operations; etc.), but the dispatch group seems to entail the least refactoring of this code. Regardless, hopefully this illustrates the basic idea: Make the final reload only be triggered when the other asynchronous requests are done.

Comment: could also use NSOperationQueue with a block operation

Comment: Yep, that works, too. But if you're dealing with asynchronous tasks, you'd then have to make `NSOperation` subclass to wrap this asynchronous tasks (or make them synchronous some way). I frequently prefer the `NSOperation` subclass approach (nicely encapsulates the details of the network request), but I wanted to make this as simple as possible. And OP seemed to be familiar with GCD, so I wanted to keep him in his comfort zone.